# MapPartition in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a JavaRDD. I am trying to do a mapPartition and pass each row for each partition to a function which takes String as a parameter.

```
rdd.mapPartitions((Iterator<String> iter) -> {
            Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
            Iterable<String> iterable = () -> iter;
            return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                    .map(s -> dummy.method(s)) // or whatever transformation
                    .iterator();
        });
```

But I am unable to call my class function(dummy.method) inside the map. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Move `Dummy dummy = new Dummy();` inside map for the stream.

Comment: @Amit I don't know how I missed that. Thanks

Comment: Glad that I could help. I have mentioned same thing in the answer, will be great if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Dummy dummy = new Dummy();` inside map for the stream.